# Antd change Input allowClear color?

Tags: antd

I have an Antd Input and i want to change the color of allow clear to white.

```
 <Input 
    placeholder="text"
    allowClear
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a css file and customise the css class

index.css

```
.anticon {
   color: white;
}
```

Example

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Won't this change the color of all icons in the project?

Comment: @KaranSharma Yes, It will change all icon color in the project, If you want the change color of only icon in one Input then `clearIcon` property of `allowClear` as you suggested is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the `clearIcon` property of `allowClear` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/input/#API).

Example:

```js
import { CloseCircleTwoTone } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Input } from 'antd';

<Input 
    allowClear={{clearIcon:<CloseCircleTwoTone twoToneColor="#FFFFFF"/>}}
    placeholder="Karan" 
    style={{width: '100%', background: "black"}} 
    defaultValue="Custom Name"
/>
```

**Note:** You can also create your own icon/react node with white color, I have just used an existing icon from ant design.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by adding this on css file

```
.ant-input-clear-icon{
  color: white;
}
```